# How to set container id when I run docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run `docker build` I can use `-t` or `--tag` parameter to deterimne `CONTAINER ID`.

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

But when I use `docker-compose` then I cannot find this option.

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

I know that `docker-composer` can create many containers, so maybe there is possibility of set `CONTAINER ID` in `docker-compose.yml`? How to do this?

Comment: not possible to set the container id, possible to set the docker image tag. 
tag is nothing but the versioning of the image.  Here is the command to create the image with tag. 

$ docker build -t imagename:tag target-folder-path

Comment: This is incorrect if you are using docker-compose you can specify the image name on build and even version it.  you also do not need to run an additional command to build, build is available in `docker-compose up` if the docker-compose file is structured with a build command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify it in your Docker Compose file that `docker-compose` is executing on e.g. `docker-compose.yaml`.

Building and deploying works the same way. Just set the image name and tag as a [subset of build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) or specify a separate dockerfile.

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./dir
    image: username/repository:tag
```

Given that `docker-compose.yaml` running `docker-compose up` would produce the following:

```
$ docker-compose up
Building webapp
Step 1/1 : FROM hello-world
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
5b0f327be733: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1f1404e9ea1a6665e3664626c5d2cda76cf90a4df50cfee16aab1a78f58a3f95
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
 ---> 05a3bd381fc2
Successfully built 05a3bd381fc2
Successfully tagged myusername/myimagename:1.0
WARNING: Image for service webapp was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating dockercompose_webapp_1 ...
Creating dockercompose_webapp_1 ... done
Attaching to dockercompose_webapp_1
webapp_1  |
webapp_1  | Hello from Docker!
webapp_1  | This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
webapp_1  |
webapp_1  | To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
webapp_1  |  1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
webapp_1  |  2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
webapp_1  |  3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
webapp_1  |     executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
webapp_1  |  4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
webapp_1  |     to your terminal.
webapp_1  |
webapp_1  | To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
webapp_1  |  $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
webapp_1  |
webapp_1  | Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
webapp_1  |  https://cloud.docker.com/
webapp_1  |
webapp_1  | For more examples and ideas, visit:
webapp_1  |  https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/
webapp_1  |
dockercompose_webapp_1 exited with code 0

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
da057afd3277        myusername/myimagename:1.0   "/hello"                 3 minutes ago       Exited (0) 3 minutes ago                       dockercompose_webapp_1

$ ls
Dockerfile          docker-compose.yaml
```

As you can see `docker-compose up` both built the container **AND** started it.  It is also named accordingly.  So there is no need to go both `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` because `docker-compose up` will both build and start the container.  Lastly, if the container needs to be rebuilt for any reason you can simply run `docker-compose up --force-recreate` which will docker to rebuild the container and appending the build tag would recreate the image: `docker-compose up --force-recreate --build`

Comment: Question nwa srelated to the Container Id setting possibility.

Comment: i disagree. the above clearly indicates how to tag an image and use a tagged image. `image: username/repository:tag`

Comment: This is useless, the Container ID we are trying to set is still a random bunch of chars.  This is the problem I and the question is trying to solve.   I know how to make the image name pretty.

Comment: @blissweb you can’t set the container Id. It’s generated by Docker as a result of the build process.  You should use the container name or if you are trying to find/do something specific you should use a label. Be warned, Docker is now deprecated across all cloud container environments. It has been replaced by cri-o.

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD I know that's the real answer, I'm gonna write my  answer soon with possible workarounds.   ps. the core docker foundations are still usable everywhere, and besides, mine is a non-cloud system.

Answer (score 1):

the -t option to `docker build` doesn't set something called `CONTAINER ID`. In fact, it has nothing to do with a container. The output of `docker build` is an *image*, which is named based on the -t option. `docker build -t myorg:myimage .` creates an image called `myorg:myimage` that you can use *later* to build containers, or push to the docker registry so that you can later use it to build a container.

The equivalent in docker-compose is `docker-compose build`, not `docker-compose up`.  To specify an image tag in docker-compose build, you use both the `build` and the `image` tags on a service in the compose file- in that case, using `docker-compose build` will build the image based on the `build` directive, and tag the output using the `image` tag.

Comment: you don't need to go `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` because `docker-compose up` will build the container if it has been given that directive in the `docker-compose.yaml` .

Comment: This is...true. If you run `docker-compose up` or `docker run` and the image required for a container doesn't currently exist on the machine, docker will go through a process to try and get that image. One of the things it will do is  running `docker-compose build` if there is a build directive in the yaml file. However, it only does this if the image doesn't exist- if you changed your dockerfile after the first time you launched, you would have to explicitly call `build` to get the changes picked up. They really are two separate commands and should be thought of as such.

Comment: that is incorrect, if you have any changes in your dockerfile you only need to run `docker-compose up --force-recreate` to have it find the changes and rebuild the image, so again, there is no need to run 2 commands when the docker up command covers both. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: So I just tried it, and that does not appear to be the case... and even if it was, understanding that there is a difference between an IMAGE and a CONTAINER is super important to successfully using Docker to develop software, and I can't imagine why you would explicitly argue that this understanding is not useful, especially in the context of someone who doesn't understand the difference between the two based on the question?

Comment: Again, I disagree and I do not see a point two commands.  If the image needs to be rebuilt you run `docker-compose up --force-recreate --build`, so there is no need for two commands when `docker-compose up` will do both.  Lastly, I do understand the context of the question which is why i've gone to great lengths to show that there is no need for two commands.  So one could argue that this is in-depth understanding of how compose builds and creates images.